# Android custom xml tag in main.xml

Tags: android, xml, tags

I'm modifying the source code of a terminal emulator program for Android that contains the following confusing xml code in the linear layout of main.xml:

```
<com.vtrandal.bluesentry.EmulatorView
    android:id="@+id/emulatorView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />
```

This same xml code also appears in another xml file also in /res/layout along with main.xml. I can see that it appears to begin with a custom tag created using my package name. But why? How is this possible and why would someone want something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you extend a View to create a custom component, you need a way to add this objects to the xml layout. You do that by using the full class name, including the package name. The [link to the dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) the Nicholas posted previously explains it.

The attributes used inside that tag can be either attributes used for the View you are extending, or custom attributes defined in a new schema.

You can follow a nice tutorial about this here: http://www.anddev.org/creating_custom_views_-_the_togglebutton-t310.html

Comment: Thanks @Aleadam I will have a look at those links. But I don't see that anything is being extended - just created out of the blue.

Comment: How is `class EmulatorView` defined?

Comment: It's not being defined anywhere. All I have is what I originally posted:

Comment: It would seem like there should be a class `com.vtrandal.bluesentry.EmulatorView` in your package (extending probably `com.googlecode.android_scripting.terminal.EmulatorView`). Maybe is a class in a jar included in the project?

Comment: Sorry @Aleadam for taking so long to rely. I have one jar in project and it is not EmulatorView. It is for AndroidPlot. So I don't know where to look except that @nicholas.hauschild provided documentation that says this the syntax for creating custom components and views in Android.

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax for [creating custom components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) and views in Android.

Comment: your answer is so concise and correct. How do I vote for you?

Comment: @Vince:  Well, you have already voted for Aleadam, and you can only choose one correct answer (you can change what you consider the correct answer, but that is not necessary in this case).  You can upvote or downvote someone's answers or questions using the arrows surrounding the numbers next to the question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly is confusing. I'll assume its `com.vtrandal.bluesentry.EmulatorView`
 part. This is name of the class that will be instantiated when inflating xml file.

If you got used to something like this:

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/emulatorView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
/>
```

Then you should know that this is because `TextView` is located in `android.widget`, and you should've wrote this:

```
<android.widget.TextView
   android:id="@+id/emulatorView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
/>
```

But because inflater knows about several special packages (`android.widget`, `android.view`, `android.webkit`) you can skip them in xml.